# Can I pass my own data (object) back from passport.use('local') to passport.authenticate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I want to pass my own data from passport.use to passport.authenticate.

I thought that the info parameter in 
`passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info)`
could be used for that.

So is there a way to doing this ?

My auth route

```
    passport.authenticate('local-register', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err); // 500 status
      }
      console.log(info);
      if (info) {
        console.log('rendering info ' + info);
        return res.render('auth/register', { info });
      } else {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(409).render('auth/register');
        }
        req.login(user, err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
          }
          return res.redirect('auth/profile');
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

My config file

```
module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    'local-register',
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        ...
      },
      (req, email, password, done) => {
        // Check if form is filled out correctly
        let errors = [];

        //check for same email
        SCUser.findOne({ 'local.email': req.body.email }, (err, local) => {
          if (local) errors.push({ text: 'Email already in use.' });

          //check for same passwords
          ...

          //check for password length
          ...

          //abort if errors are found
          if (errors.length > 0) {
            const info = {
              errors: errors,
              ...,
            };
            console.log(`returning info ${info}`);
            return done(null, info);
          }

          //form is filled in correctly create a user
          else {
          ...
          }
       ...
```

Random things I've tried so far:

Adding `, form_validate` behind `info` & changing the required variables to `form_validate` doesn't pass it through to the auth file.

There are probably better ways to handle form validation, haven't looked that up yet, if you have any suggestions please tell me, but I still kind of want to know if it would be possible to pass custom objects through passports methods.

Comment: According to the docs, you can pass the user object on success and an info object on failure. Have you actually tried to see? Experiment first, and if you have issues, then post them to SO. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash  `` An optional info argument will be passed, containing additional details provided by the strategy's verify callback.`` Info isn't passed on failure but on the verify callback ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  I see 'form validation' mentioned.  Passport has absolutely nothing to do with that task; it is only for authenticating a user.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example from the documentation:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

If you determine that the username/pass are not correct, you can call `done` with the last parameter being any object that you wish

```
return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password", otherData: "my other data"});
```

And, if it is a success, you can pass the user, but there is no reason you can't add more data to the user, or pass something completely different.

```
return done(null, {username: "user123", otherData: myData, customString: "myString"});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)